# free mac appearance regarding utilities / softwares

Tags: macos, mouse, desktop, themes

When I was working on windows. I was used to install CrystalXP, And many other softwares - themes for windows. The appearance of the terminal - if looks good, you feel better & like to work with nice one.

Same way, Is there any other software / themes for mac osx ( freely available = more priority )

- for changing mouse pointers
- for changing default appearance ( as we do install vista appearance in xp )
- appearance regarding theme links / software links
- any help for making beautiful.

Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge.

Sagar.

Comment: Plz Inform me in comment. If it is a duplicate.

Comment: @Sagar: if you change the color of the background, the menu color will follow. (Go to System Preferences -> Desktop & Screen Saver.) I'm not sure about changing color or look of the dock.

Comment: Ok. Ok I was just giving example of windows. I have gone through "http://interfacelift.com/themes-mac/" link & It is something like i wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are some things out there to do this (sort of), part of the point of the way OS X is constructed is to maintain UI consistency.  I recommend learning to enjoy the UI as is, simply because modifying it will be more trouble than it's worth.  You can modify the colors and such, and there are LOTS of utilities to extend the UI, like QuickSilver, LaunchBar, CandyBar for icon themes and others.  You'll find that overall they are more about functionality than about making it look like an LCARS interface or pay homage to the latest blockbuster.

You may want to look in to [ShapeShifter](http://unsanity.com/haxies/shapeshifter), but I don't believe it works with OS versions newer than Tiger.  [InterfaceLIFT](http://interfacelift.com/themes-mac/) has a ShapeShifter themes section.

Comment: Ah, the cry of the Mac: take it or leave it...

Comment: Some people want customization, others want something well put together out of the box.  There is no right or wrong here, just preference.

Comment: Mainly because some people like to get work done with their system while others I guess like to look at it?  I've never seen a reason to "theme" OS X, it's functional as-is.

Comment: @Phoebus: I find both your arguments pretty uncompelling. One person's "well put together" is another person's fugly. It's pretty normal for people to have preferences (as you mention) in terms of appearances. As for functional and getting work done, again sure computers are for work, but they are also for fun. Most computer users (of non-Mac operating systems) take it for granted that they can make lots of changes to the visuals of their computer. Apple's attitude - we did it right, so shut up - is the exception, not the rule.

Comment: And I don't really care, Telemachus.  That's kind of the point.   If you want to make lots of little UI tweaks, OS X is probably not the system for you.  That doesn't make anyone wrong or right, that's just a fact.

The entire idea behind Apple's product is a system that attempts to operate with consistency.  That's what they are selling.  It would be antithetical to their product to change that.  If that's not the product you are looking for, then that's that - at that point I'd look elsewhere.

Comment: A great comment by @Telemachus. He's exactly right.

Comment: Hey Hey Hey ! plz. Stop. I was just asking for something like - changing dock color - good background - menu color - all these collection is called a "Theme" - in xp. & so I was asking same for osx if available.

Comment: @Phoebus: I deleted my last comment (maybe right before you answered it), because I thought I was just picking a fight and decided I shouldn't. Many people regard Apple's UI as well-built and sleek. No question. Put simply, however, I hate the attitude by Apple (and many Mac-fans) that anyone who wants to tweak it is an idiot. That said, you have every right not to care what I think.

Comment: @Tel I deleted my response as well, sorry for fighting:)

Answer (score 1):

If you are feeling heroically energetic, you can install an entirely different desktop environment on a Mac. Mostly out of pure stubborn curiosity, I got Gnome working (via [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/) - [Fink](http://www.finkproject.org/) also has Gnome and KDE), and apparently KDE is even easier. It's very hard to do, and the result was a bit fragile, in my experience. But perhaps things are better now (I did it about a year and change ago).

Beyond that, you might take a look at [CandyBar](http://www.panic.com/candybar/) for icon themes. Changing the desktop background is trivial, but also not a real change of theme.

Comment: Sir - CandyBar is a paid application. I asked for free. However, Thanks for your response. CandyBar is a good application. I have gone through.